# How to delete item to list in react?

Tags: reactjs

Also added a delete button but its not working, it says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deleteItem')" What am I doing wrong here?

```html
<script type="text/babel">
            "use strict";
            
            class App extends React.Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                  items: [],
                  currentItem: {
                    text: "",
                    key: ""
                  }
                };
                this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
                this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
                this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
                this.setUpdate = this.setUpdate.bind(this);
              }
              handleInput(e) {
                this.setState({
                  currentItem: {
                    text: e.target.value,
                    key: Date.now()
                  }
                });
              }
              addItem(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const newItem = this.state.currentItem;
                console.log(newItem);
                if (newItem.text !== "") {
                  const newItems = [...this.state.items, newItem];
                  this.setState({
                    items: newItems, // <-- should be new items array built above
                    currentItem: {
                      text: "",
                      key: ""
                    }
                  });
                }
              }

              deleteItem(key){
                const filteredItems= this.state.items.filter(item =>
                item.key!==key);
                this.setState({
                items: filteredItems
                })
            }

            setUpdate(text, key) {
               const items = this.state.items;
               items.map(item => {
                   if(item.key===key) {
                       item.text=text;
                   }
               })
               this.setState({
                   items: items
               })
            }
            
              render() {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <form id="to-do-form" onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                        value={this.state.currentItem.text}
                        onChange={this.handleInput}
                      />
                      <button type="submit">Add</button>
                    </form>
                    <ListItem items={this.state.items} 
                    deleteItem = {this.deleteItem}
                    setUpdate = {this.setUpdate}/>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }
            
            class ListItem extends React.Component {
              render() {
                return (
                  <div>
                    {this.props.items.map((item) => {
                      return (
                        <div className="list" key={item.key}>
                          <p><input type="text" 
                            id={item.key} 
                            value={item.text} 
                            onChange ={
                                (e) => {
                                    this.props.setUpdate(e.target.value, item.key)
                                }
                            }
                            /><button onClick={() => this.prop.deleteItem(item.key)}>Ta bort</button></p>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }
            
            ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
            </script>
```

This is the first time I'm coding i react and I am trying to add a new list item to the list in but I get "TypeError: e.render is not a function" in the console... I want to have all my code in the HTML file like I have right now. Can you see what I am doing wrong here? This is my code so far:

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
"use strict";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            currentItem: {
                text:'',
                key:''
            }
        }
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }
    handleInput(e) {
        this.setState({
            currentItem: {
                text: e.target.value,
                key: Date.now()
            }
        })
    }
    addItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newItem = this.state.currentItem;
        console.log(newItem);
        if(newItem.text!=="") {
            const items=[...this.state.items, newItem];
            this.setState({
                items: newItems,
                currentItem: {
                    text:'',
                    key:''
                }
            })
        }
    }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <form id="to-do-form" onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text"
                value={this.state.currentItem.text}
                onChange={this.handleInput}/>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
            <ListItem items = {this.state.items}></ListItem>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const items = props.items;
        const ListItems = items.map(items => {
            return <div className="list" key="item.key">
                    <p>{item.text}</p>
                </div>
        })
      return (
        <div>{ListItems}</div>
      )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few misnamed variables. When adding items to `this.state.items` you were referencing an undeclared `newItems` variable when it should have been the `items` variable declared locally.

Additionally, the `ListItem` component was trying to save the passed props into a local class variable. Saving props locally is an anti-pattern in React, just render directly from the passed props values. `ListItem` also was not providing a `render` lifecycle method to return anything to render to the UI.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
"use strict";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      currentItem: {
        text: "",
        key: ""
      }
    };
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }
  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      currentItem: {
        text: e.target.value,
        key: Date.now()
      }
    });
  }
  addItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = this.state.currentItem;
    console.log(newItem);
    if (newItem.text !== "") {
      const newItems = [...this.state.items, newItem];
      this.setState({
        items: newItems, // <-- should be new items array built above
        currentItem: {
          text: "",
          key: ""
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="to-do-form" onSubmit={this.addItem}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Text"
            value={this.state.currentItem.text}
            onChange={this.handleInput}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
        <ListItem items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="list" key={item.key}>
              <p>{item.text}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
</script>
```

Comment: updated my question, I also added a deletebutton but its not working... can you se what is wrong?

Comment: @sinusa Typo, it should be `this.props.deleteItem(item.key)` not `this.prop.deleteItem(item.key)`. Class components it's always `this.props`, with an "s". You are also mutating the state in the update function, and should really be using functional state updates to update state from the previous state. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-delete-item-to-list-in-react-dw6sx) example.